# Blau'sN Index of diversity

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using Blau's index of diversity for my analysis
BlauN= 1- ∑Nk(Nk-1)/N(N-1)
Where Nk=Absolute freq of group members in Kth category and N= Total number of members

Data consists of:
250 cases, 50 groups, and F_eth (factor variable with group member ethnicity as one of the five categories: Caucasian, Asian, South Asian, First nations, and Others)

An extract of my data is here:

```
> head(d1h3.1)
  case group     F_eth
1    1     1     Asian
2    2     1 Caucasian
3    3     1 Caucasian
4    4     1 Caucasian
5    5     2     Asian
6    6     2     Asian
```

The final output should give me group wise summary of Blau’s Index in a new col. I was trying to mutate two cols i.e., Nk and N using dplyr so that I can finally create BlauN but am stuck at creating Nk.